# Assembly: file descriptor 0 or 2 for reading user input

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am learning assembly and there were different file descriptors used for reading user input.

For reading keyboard entry, I was expecting file descriptor 0 (stdin), but came across this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm) where file descriptor 2 (stderr) was used.

```
;Read and store the user input
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 2
mov ecx, num  
mov edx, 5          ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
int 80h
```

However, I've commonly seen ebx set as 0 instead:

```
;Read and store the user input
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num  
mov edx, 5          ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
int 80h
```

I have tried setting ebx to 0 and 2, and they both work fine without issues. Can you explain to me which is the better option to use? Or is there other approaches I should take for best practices?

Comment: `0` is the correct value for `stdin`. `2` may work if it's connected to the same actual device as `0`. As soon as you apply some redirection, that will no longer work (e.g. `foo 2>/dev/null`).

Comment: File descriptor 0 is standard input.  Some tools use file descriptor 2 (standard error) to read interactive input while processing data as it's commonly attached to a terminal, even if input is redirected. YMMV, but I strongly recommend you to use file descriptor 0 for input unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better option is to use the STDIN file descriptor (No. 0). Nevertheless, you can use the STDERR streaM (No. 2) - actually an output stream - for reading:

> [The stderr stream is expected to be open for reading and writing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html)

This is a practical workaround, if the STDIN stream is redirected.

Comment: related: [How does \`less\` take data from stdin while still be able to read commands from user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452757)  (By opening `/dev/tty` instead of the historical method of reading stderr, but it still queries the screen size from *stdout* to detect if its own output was redirected.)